# Strange split method

Tags: java, split

I have a problem about the split method. I’d like to write the program that I invoke split  method with

`("a?b?gf#sad", "#?")`,

it will return

`[a,?,b,?,gf,#,sad]`.

Could somebody tell how can I solve this question? Thank you very much.

Comment: try something around String.split... :)

Comment: This is not a "please do my homework for me" website. What did you try yourself? Post your code, and ask a specific question about where you get stuck.

Comment: Beats me why you accepted an un-voted complicated 5-line solution over a well voted elegant 1-line solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StringTokenizer:

```
    String s = "a?b?gf#sad";
    final StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, "#?", true);
    String[] a = new String[stringTokenizer.countTokens()];
    int i = 0;
    while(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        a[i++] = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Prints:

```
 [a, ?, b, ?, gf, #, sad]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I have not learned this method, I will try to understand how it work. :)

Comment: @CookyKao I've seen you say that and things similar to that many times. I really hope you are. I've known CS students who get answers from other people without ever truly learning so do put in the effort to understand what's going on or you'll eventually reach a place where no one will give you the answers and you'll be unable to figure them out yourself.

Comment: @AHungerArtist Thank you for replying. I actually know what I am asking and doing. Finding excuses is not good, but I always make effort to figure out the question at first before asking. Now I will try to change my way to prevent this way happen again.

Answer (score 2):

This one's a bit tricky, so I'm going to "spoon feed" you. But I'll show my reasoning.

Firstly, the fact that no input is *consumed* means the regex is a zero-width match (and so doesn't consume anything). That means a look-ahead and/or a look-behind.

Secondly, although your input sample is far from an exhaustive example, it seems that splitting is done *beside* `?` or `#`.

Putting these two facts together gives us this solution:

```
"a?b?gf#sad".split("(?<=[?#])|(?=[?#])");
```

Here's what the regex means:

- `(?<=[?#])` is a look-behind asserting that the previous character is a `?` or `#`
- `(?=[?#])` is a look-ahead asserting that the next character is a `?` or `#`
- `A|B` means "A or B", so the whole regex is either of the look arounds

Here's a test:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a?b?gf#sad".split("(?<=[?#])|(?=[?#])")));
```

Output:

```
[a, ?, b, ?, gf, #, sad]
```

Note that if you wanted to broaden the splitting to be "any non-word character" (rather than just `?` or `#`) you could simply change the split regex to `"(?<=\\W)|(?=\\W)"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to split on **word boundaries**, and that exists in the javadoc of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), see *"Boundary matchers."* In fact as this is homework, read the documentation; there are nice jewels of expressive power.

```
"a?b?gf#sad".split("\\b");
```

Consider also what would happen for two special signs: `"a?#b?#gf##sad"`.